# Does an app that amplify your voice instantly exist?

Tags: android, voice-recording

I wonder if there is any app existed that I can either speak to the android phone directly or speaking into a clip-on mic, and the app uses the phone as a speaker to amplify the voice instantly?

I am not trying to record the voice, but just instantly make it louder.

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. But there are issues for doing real time audio manipulations on Android (which they have gotten closer to fixing but the problem still exists). Read up on it here: http://superpowered.com/androidaudiopathlatency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like this app?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ad960009.app.MicToSpeaker&hl=en). There are [many similar apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bitplane.android.microphone).

Comment: Yes and no, yes about the concept, but these apps are of really bad quality, there have extreme delays and echos if you have actually tried using them.

Comment: If you use OpenSL ES instead of AudioTrack you can decrease delay, but not very much. The phone itself must also support low-latency audio, like Galaxy S6 for example which was specifically marketed to musicians.

Comment: Thanks, never knew this is such a technical challenge even in recent days.